# Layout engine calculation cross dependency

Tags: layout

I'm working on a GUI layout engine.
It is built as a tree, where any so called "Widget" can have an unlimited amount of child "Widgets" inside.
When evaluating the final position and size of a widget, there are a set of constraints you can apply to any widget.

**The ones relevant to my problem are the following:**

- `The widgets size can be a percentage of the size of its parent.`
  To make this possible, we have to traverse the tree from the trunk to the leaves.
  In other words: The parents size must be known to calculate the childs size.
- `A widget can be set to always grow with the children.`
  To make this possible, we have to traverse the tree from the leaves to the trunk.
  In other words: The childrens sizes must be known to calculate the parents size.

There is a conflict in the order of operations here.
How can this be solved?